# Posting dynamically created form elements alongside hard coded html form

Tags: jquery

I have this html form

```
<div class="allsubjects">
<form class="profile">
<label>Names</label>
<input type="text" name="names" value="" />
<label>City</label>
<input type="text" name="city" value="" />
</form>
</div>

<button class="add">
Add
</button>
```

which am using to enter some data. Alongside this form is a dynamically created form field

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".add" ).on( "click", function() {
$( ".profile" ).append( '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><label>Subject</label><input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="First row, second input"></div></div>');

});
});
```

This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5o52ueey/9/

Is there a way i can post the ordinary form and receive the input as usual and get the dynamically posted form info as an array?.

Comment: You want to submit form data and then receive it back from the server? And also get the second form's data as an array?

Comment: I want to post the data,and get the dynamic  data as an array and the other form data as i would receive and ordinary for with `$_POST` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below using AJAX. Use the Current button for creating dynamic field & a new button for submitting the form.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".add" ).on("click", function() {

    $( ".profile" ).append( '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><label>Subject</label><input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="First row, second input"></div></div>');

    $(this).attr("disabled", true);

});

$(".profile").on("click", "#submit", function(){

    //Post Data using AJAX

    var formData = {name: $("#names").val(), city: $("#city").val(), subject: $("#subject").val()};
    console.log(formData);

    var postDataObj = {
                    url: "YOUR_SERVER_FILE",
                    type: "post",
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(data){
                       //Response Data From Server
                    }
    }
    console.log(postDataObj);       

    $.ajax(postDataObj);



});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="allsubjects">
<form class="profile">
<label>Names</label>
<input type="text" name="names" id="names" value="" />
<label>City</label>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
</div>

<button class="add">
Add Subject
</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I serialized array https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

```
'submit #er': function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var names = event.target.names.value;
  var examname = event.target.examname.value;
  var classname = event.target.classname.value;
  // var result = event.target.results.value;
  var formData = $('#er').serializeArray();
   console.log(formData);  
}
```

This works well with dynamically created form fields.